# Having trouble with first time task of uploading files

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library

I just installed your library and am trying to use it to upload files to our sharepoint site. Then be able to do file lists and download them. Effectively have a tool on our site not store documents locally, but rather in sharepoint where the rest of the company can access them.

I am able to authenticate and even list our user profiles so I know I'm connected.

But when trying to upload a file, I get an error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'File Not Found.' in /home/jsatzusreof/public_html/mlkcompanies.com/RETracker/vendor/vgrem/php-spo/src/Runtime/OData/ODataClientRequest.php:110 Stack trace: #0 /home/jsatzusreof/public_html/mlkcompanies.com/RETracker/vendor/vgrem/php-spo/src/Runtime/OData/ODataClientRequest.php(61): Office365\PHP\Client\Runtime\OData\ODataClientRequest->validateResponse('{"error":{"code...') #1 /home/jsatzusreof/public_html/mlkcompanies.com/RETracker/vendor/vgrem/php-spo/src/Runtime/ClientRuntimeContext.php(134): Office365\PHP\Client\Runtime\OData\ODataClientRequest->executeQuery() #2 /home/jsatzusreof/public_html/mlkcompanies.com/RETracker/vendor/vgrem/php-spo/src/SharePoint/ClientContext.php(83): Office365\PHP\Client\Runtime\ClientRuntimeContext->executeQuery() #3 /home/jsatzusreof/public_html/mlkcompanies.com/temp/test_sharepoint.php(20): Office365\PHP\Client\SharePoint\ClientContext->executeQuery() #4 /home/jsatzusreof/public_html/mlkcompanies.com/temp/test_sharepoint.php(87): u in /home/jsatzusreof/public_html/mlkcompanies.com/RETracker/vendor/vgrem/php-spo/src/Runtime/OData/ODataClientRequest.php on line 110
```

My code is:

```
require_once ('/home/jsatzusreof/public_html/mlkcompanies.com/RETracker/vendor/autoload.php');

use Office365\PHP\Client\Runtime\Auth\AuthenticationContext;
use Office365\PHP\Client\SharePoint\ClientContext;
use Office365\PHP\Client\Runtime\ClientRuntimeContext;
use Office365\PHP\Client\SharePoint\SPList;
use Office365\PHP\Client\SharePoint\Web;

function uploadFileIntoFolder(ClientContext $ctx, $localPath, $targetFolderUrl)
{
    echo "$localPath, $targetFolderUrl<BR>\n";
    $fileName = basename($localPath);
    $fileCreationInformation = new \Office365\PHP\Client\SharePoint\FileCreationInformation();
    $fileCreationInformation->Content = file_get_contents($localPath);
    $fileCreationInformation->Url = $fileName;

    $uploadFile = $ctx->getWeb()->getFolderByServerRelativeUrl($targetFolderUrl)->getFiles()->add($fileCreationInformation);
    $ctx->executeQuery();
    echo "File {$uploadFile->getProperty('Name')} has been uploaded<BR>\r\n";
}

$webUrl = "https://mlkcompanies.sharepoint.com/FirstKey";
$filename = "Budget_test.xlsm";
$localFilePath = "/home/jsatzusreof/public_html/mlkcompanies.com/temp/$filename";
$targetFileUrl = "Documents/$filename";

try
{
    $authCtx = new AuthenticationContext($webUrl);
    $authCtx->acquireTokenForUser($userName,$password);
    echo "Authentication succeeded<BR>\n";
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    echo 'Authentication failed: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
$ctx = new ClientContext($webUrl,$authCtx);

$results = uploadFileIntoFolder($ctx, $localFilePath, $targetFileUrl);
```